# Get build error in WKNavigationDelegateEvents+Rx of Pod after upgrading to Xcode 14.0.1

Tags: xcode

I have upgrade my MacBook to MacOS Ventura version 13.0, and Xcode to version 14.0.1 respectively.  Everything seem ok.  Once I tried to rebuild my mobile apps, it got error in the WKNavigationDelegateEvents+Rx file, and the lines of coding getting error are as below.  They are belong to Pod library.

```
 /// Xcode give error when selectors results into having same signature
 /// because of swift style you get for example:
 /// Ambiguous use of 'webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)'
 /// please see this link for further understanding
 /// https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3062
    static let decidePolicyNavigationResponse = #selector(WKNavigationDelegate.webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:) as ((WKNavigationDelegate) -> (WKWebView, WKNavigationResponse, @escaping(WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) -> Void)?)
    static let decidePolicyNavigationAction = #selector(WKNavigationDelegate.webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:) as ((WKNavigationDelegate) -> (WKWebView, WKNavigationAction, @escaping(WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) -> Void)?)
```

The Error Message is : Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

My application works fine before conducting the upgrade.  Hence, would anyone have idea about this?  Thanks in advance for your valuable advice and helping hand and assistance.

I have no idea what to do, so I stuck in here.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the latest release of RxWebKit : [2.0.1](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxWebKit/releases/tag/2.0.1)